# Is there a way to show a modal dialog in Gmail add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Is there a way to show a modal dialog in Gmail add-on, similar like in Spreadsheets add-on

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, title);
```

Looks like no and the only way to display some UI to a user is to use [Cards](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/cards)

However, I would like to be sure that it's correct. Couldn't find any article that it's not possible and working solution as well.

Thanks for any comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. If you want to add a UI to GMail using an Add-on you have to use their [Cards](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/cards) feature. You can read the [restriction here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions):

> **Use client-side scripting**
>
> You can't design a custom UI for your add-on using HTML, CSS and Javascript. Gmail add-ons use a widget-based approach to building user interfaces. This allows the add-on to work well on desktop and mobile platforms without requiring you to build an interface for each.