# What am I missing with this add-on that creates an overlay based off a field submission

Tags: google-apps-script

Templates into HTML, whose table cell values is set according to the field values submitted

I can't seem to get the card service to evaluate my HTML template. I believe the cause is due to my variables not being passed along. Could someone help fix my code?

```
    function buildAddOn(e) {
  // Activate temporary Gmail add-on scopes.
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

  var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);

  // Create a section for that contains all user Labels.
  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
    .setHeader("<font color=\"#1257e0\"><b>Quotation Fields</b></font>");
  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
var gdsInfo = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setMultiline(true)
    .setFieldName('gds_info')
  .setTitle('GDS Information')
  .setHint("Paste the entire quote from Sabre's Clipboard");
  var action = CardService.newAction();
  action.setFunctionName('startFormat');
  action.setParameters({data: 'gdsInfo'});
  var startFormat = CardService.newTextButton()
  .setText("Format")
  .setOnClickAction(action);
  // Add the checkbox group to the section.
  section.addWidget(gdsInfo).addWidget(startFormat);
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
               .setTitle('GDS Format: Sabre')
    .setImageUrl('https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/label_googblue_48dp.png'))
    .addSection(section)
    .build();

  return [card];
}

function startFormat(text) {
  var theValues = text;

  **REDACTED FORM HANDLING CODE**

  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  htmlTemplate.data = trips;
    var htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
        .setTitle('sample');
    return htmlOutput;
  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNotification(CardService.newNotification()
          .setText("Formatting/Constructing Draft"))
      .build();
}
```

**RESULT**
    TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. [line: 151, function: startFormat, file: Code]

EDIT

index.html (Please excuse the messy code, a LOT of testing has happened today)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;"><div class="container" style="position: absolute;">
<table style="
    border-collapse: collapse;text-color:#000000;
    overflow: hidden;border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);"><thead>
<thead style="background-color: #e42f38;"><tr>
<th style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;">#</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;">Airline</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;">Flight(s)</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;">Depart</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;">Arrive</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;">Class</th>
<th style="width: 80px;padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;">Price</th>
  </tr></thead><tbody style="">
    <? for(var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++){ ?>
    <?for(var j = 0; j <data[0][i].flights.length; j++){?>
    <tr style="background-color: <?if(data[0][i].num % 2 === 0){?>#e42f38<?}else{?>#fff<?} ?>">
    <td style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;"><?= data[0][i].num ?></td>
          <td style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;"><?= data[0][i].flights[j].airline?></td>
          <td style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;"><?=data[0][i].flights[j].flightnum?></td>
          <?function tConvert (time) {
  // Check correct time format and split into components
  time = time.toString ().match (/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)?$/) || [time];

  if (time.length > 1) { // If time format correct
    time = time.slice (1);  // Remove full string match value
    time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? 'A' : 'P'; // Set AM/PM
    time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12; // Adjust hours
  }
  return time.join (''); // return adjusted time or original string
} function nth(d) {if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th'; 
          switch (d % 10) {
          case 1:  return "st";
          case 2:  return "nd";
          case 3:  return "rd";
          default: return "th";
          }
          }?>
          <td style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;"><?= tConvert(data[0][i].flights[j].departtime)?><br>
          <div style="padding-top:2px;"><?=data[0][i].flights[j].departdate ?></div></td>
          <td style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;"><?= tConvert(data[0][i].flights[j].arrivetime)?><br>
          <div style="padding-top:2px;"><?=data[0][i].flights[j].departdate ?></div></td>
          <td style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;"><?= data[0][i].flights[j].class?></td>
          <td style="padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #000;text-align: center;"><?=data[0][i].price?></td>
        <? }?>
        </tr><?}?></tbody>
    </table></div><style>
tbody {
    tr {
        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        }
    }
    td {
        position: relative;
        &:hover {
            &:before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                top: -9999px;
                bottom: -9999px;
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
                z-index: -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
</style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the code to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for adding some of your code, but your error "Cannot read property "length" from undefined" leads me to believe that there is some call to "length()" or the equivalent; I don't see any such call in the code you've provided ?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context in this. The template is being evaluated, I did not include the HTML file which contains several functions that call the length of the data's array and their subarrays.

Comment: Alright; you have three .length calls here:
    <? for(var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++){ ?>
    <?for(var j = 0; j <data[0][i].flights.length; j++){?>
    if (time.length > 1) { // If time format correct
Do you know which is giving the error ?

Comment: I would have to think it was the first one, if the multi-dimensional array is not being passed into the function

"var gdsInfo = CardService.newTextInput()"
"var action = CardService.newAction();"
"action.setFunctionName('startFormat');"
"action.setParameters({data: 'gdsInfo'});"
"function startFormat(text) {
  var theValues = text;"
 "var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  htmlTemplate.data = trips;"
 "var startFormat = CardService.newTextButton()
  .setText("Format")
  .setOnClickAction(action);"

Comment: I think I've found the fix, how do I get the evaluated HTML file to display over Gmail, preferably in a modal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993322/is-there-a-way-to-show-a-modal-dialog-in-gmail-add-on